# element is not getting clicked even it got validated from dropdown list in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to select the element from the list. With the below code it figures out the correct element. But it doesn't click on the element. Not getting how to proceed.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName" data-sap-ui="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" class="sapMSlt sapMSltDefault sapMSltHoverable sapMSltMinWidth sapMSltWithArrow" aria-labelledby="__label7 __test0-defaultXML--idQueueName-label" role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">
<input id="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName-hiddenInput" aria-multiline="false" aria-readonly="true" tabindex="-1" class="sapUiPseudoInvisibleText">
<label id="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName-label" for="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName" class="sapMSltLabel" aria-live="polite">- Select -</label>
<span id="__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName-arrow" class="sapMSltArrow"></span>
<ul style="width:100%;max-width:100%" class="sapMSelectList" role="listbox">
<li tabindex="0" class="sapMSelectListItem sapMSelectListItemBase sapMSelectListItemBaseHoverable sapMSelectListItemBaseSelected" role="option" aria-selected="true" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="1">- Select -</li>
<li tabindex="0" class="sapMSelectListItem sapMSelectListItemBase sapMSelectListItemBaseHoverable" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="2">sap/smtest/test/a1</li>
<li tabindex="0" class="sapMSelectListItem sapMSelectListItemBase sapMSelectListItemBaseHoverable" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="3">sap/smtest/test/test</li>
<li tabindex="0" class="sapMSelectListItem sapMSelectListItemBase sapMSelectListItemBaseHoverable" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-setsize="4" aria-posinset="4">sap/smtest/test/tt</li>
</ul>
</div>


import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public boolean selectn() {
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 1) {
        try {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement list1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName\"]/ul"));
            list1.click();
            List<WebElement> Listnw = list1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            for(WebElement li : Listnw) {
                if (li.getText().equals("sap/smtest/test/a1")) {
                    li.click();
                }
            }
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There might be 2 reasons, 1, Your found element is not the element having `onclick` event. 2, Your element need wait for ajax to attach `onclick` on it, and you had clicked it before it was clickable. For more specific answer, you should provide URL so we can have a look.

Comment: can you copy/paste you html code?

Answer (score 0):

After `WebElement list1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__test0-defaultXML--idQueueName\"]/ul"));`.
Please add `list1.click();` and see if it works.
Leave the code below as it is.

Comment: after adding this line it moves to non intractable exception..

Comment: Find **WebElement list1** by **Absolute xPath**, currently you are using relative xPath. And after clicking **list1**, please add some wait as `browser.sleep(500)`.

Comment: i have added the html code and my latest code.. Plz check